# React Context provider not working in Next.js dynamic route

Tags: next.js, react-context

I have a Next.js dynamic page that displays detailed information about a selected restaurant. The problem is, despite wrapping its return statement with the appropriate context provider, it throws an error implying that the context provider is not being used. This is odd because there seems to be no issues when I apply the same logic to static pages. Unless of course, it works differently with dynamic pages in the app directory.
I'm accessing the page from a link in `fetchDisplayRestaurants`.

Wrapping the layout component with the context provider will likely work, but I opted to selectively wrap the components to avoid unnecessary re-renders. Is there way to solve this without wrapping the root layout with the context providers?

Code:

**/app/restaurants/[slug]/page.tsx:**

```tsx
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Toggle } from "components/Toggle";
import Pickup from "components/Pickup";
import Delivery from "components/Delivery";
import RestaurantMenu from "components/RestaurantMenu";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import {
  DeliveryProvider,
  useDeliveryContext,
} from "../../context/DeliveryContext";
import {
  RestaurantMenuProvider,
  useRestaurantMenuContext,
} from "app/context/RestaurantMenuContext";
// import { LocationProvider } from "app/context/LocationContext";

export default function RestaurantDetailsPage() {
  const { restaurantData, menuData, isLoading } = useRestaurantMenuContext();

  const { isDelivery, toggleDelivery } = useDeliveryContext();

  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      // Data not loaded yet, check for error after delay
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setError(true);
      }, 5000);

      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  const handleRetry = () => {
    setError(false);
  };

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        Error occurred while loading data.{" "}
        <button onClick={handleRetry}>Retry</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (!isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  console.log("menuData", menuData);
  const params = useParams();
  const { slug } = params;
  const str = slug?.toString().replace(/-/g, " ");
  console.log(`str: ${str}`);
  const capitalizedSlug = str
    ?.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/(^|\s)\S/g, (match) => match.toUpperCase());

  const restaurant = restaurantData.find(
    (item) => item.name === capitalizedSlug
  );
  const menu = menuData.filter(
    (item) => item.restaurantName === capitalizedSlug
  );

  return (
    <RestaurantMenuProvider>
      <DeliveryProvider>
        <div>
          {restaurant && isDelivery ? (
            <Delivery restaurant={restaurant} />
          ) : (
            <Pickup />
          )}
          <div className="pl-2 mb-8 mt-6">
            <div className="text-3xl font-semibold">{restaurant?.name}</div>
            <div className="font-semibold">4.5</div>
            <div>Open until ...</div>
            <div>Tap for hours, info and more</div>
          </div>
          <Toggle onToggle={toggleDelivery} />
          <div className="mb-3 flex justify-around">
            <div>See similar</div>
            <div>Group order</div>
          </div>
          {restaurant && <RestaurantMenu restaurant={restaurant} menu={menu} />}
        </div>
      </DeliveryProvider>
    </RestaurantMenuProvider>
  );
}
```

**app/lib/fetchDisplayRestaurants.tsx:**

```tsx
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import slugify from "slugify";
import { useLocationContext } from "app/context/LocationContext";
import { Restaurant } from "types/types";
import Image from "next/image";
import { RestaurantMenuProvider } from "app/context/RestaurantMenuContext";

export default function DisplayRestaurants({
  isLoading,
}: {
  isLoading: boolean;
}) {
  const { restaurantData, setSelectedRestaurant } = useLocationContext();
  // const { isLoading } = useRestaurantMenuContext();
  // console.log(isLoading);
  console.log(`restaurantData: ${JSON.stringify(restaurantData)}`);
  console.log(`length: `, restaurantData?.length);
  // const { setSelectedRestaurant } = useLocationContext();
  const [restaurantPlaceholders, setRestaurantPlaceholders] = useState<
    JSX.Element[]
  >([]);

  // console.log(`distance:`, restaurantData);
  const handleRestaurantClick = (restaurant: Restaurant) => {
    console.log(`RESTAURANT: `, restaurant);
    setSelectedRestaurant(restaurant);
  };

  // const filteredRestaurants = restaurantData?.filter(
  //   (restaurant) => restaurant.distance && restaurant.distance <= 1
  // );

  // console.log(`filteredRestaurants: ${JSON.stringify(filteredRestaurants)}`);
  const displayRestaurants = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <RestaurantMenuProvider>
          {restaurantData?.map((restaurant) => (
            // <Fragment key={restaurant.name}>
            <div
              key={restaurant.name}
              className="relative h-32 mt-2 mb-4 bg-black"
              onClick={() => {
                console.log(`restaurant: ${JSON.stringify(restaurant)}`);
                handleRestaurantClick(restaurant);
              }}
            >
              <div className="relative h-full">
                {restaurant.photoUrl && (
                  <Image
                    src={restaurant.photoUrl}
                    alt={restaurant.name}
                    fill
                    className="object-cover opacity-50"
                  />
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-white">
                <Link
                  href={`/restaurants/${slugify(
                    restaurant.name
                  ).toLowerCase()}`}
                >
                  <div>{restaurant.name}</div>
                </Link>
                <div>{restaurant.location}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </RestaurantMenuProvider>
      </>
    );
  };

  const showSkeleton = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {Array(5)
          .fill(null)
          .map((item, index) => {
            return (
              // <SkeletonTheme baseColor="#202020" highlightColor="#444">
              <div className="h-32 mt-2 mb-4 animate-pulse" key={index}>
                {/* // </SkeletonTheme> */}
                <div className="bg-stone-300 h-full"></div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </>
    );
  };

  return <div>{isLoading ? showSkeleton() : displayRestaurants()}</div>;
}
```

**app/context/RestaurantMenuContext.tsx:**

```tsx
"use client";

import { RestaurantMenuContextValue, Restaurant, Menu } from "types/types";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import supabase from "supabase/supabase";

const RestaurantMenuContext = createContext<
  RestaurantMenuContextValue | undefined
>(undefined);

export const useRestaurantMenuContext = (): RestaurantMenuContextValue => {
  const context = useContext(RestaurantMenuContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "useRestaurantMenuContext must be used within a RestaurantMenuProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
};

export const RestaurantMenuProvider: React.FC<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [restaurantData, setRestaurantData] = useState<Restaurant[]>([]);
  const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState<Menu[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchRestaurantData() {
      try {
        const { data: restaurantData, error: restaurantDataError } =
          await supabase
            .from("Restaurant")
            .select("id, name, photoUrl, location, latitude, longitude");
        console.log(`restaurantData: `, restaurantData);

        const { data: menuData, error: menuDataError } = await supabase
          .from("Menu")
          .select("*");

        if (restaurantDataError || menuDataError) {
          console.error(restaurantDataError);
          console.error(menuDataError);
        } else {
          setRestaurantData(restaurantData ?? []);
          setMenuData(menuData as Menu[]);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    fetchRestaurantData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <RestaurantMenuContext.Provider
      value={{ restaurantData, setRestaurantData, menuData, isLoading }}
    >
      {children}
    </RestaurantMenuContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think you can use RestaurantMenuProvider in layout.tsx.